# On decidability of an infinite dimensional dynamic system

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, norms

Consider two infinite dimensional Toeplitz integer matrices $A,B$ where $B$ is just a shift operator and an infinite dimensional vector $V_0$.

Given a prime $p$ and an infinite dimensional integer vector $U_0$ with $\|U_0\|_1\in\Bbb Z$ and $\|U_0\|_1<\infty$ is it easy to decide whether there is a $k$ such that the sequence of vectors

$$U_k=AU_{k-1}+V_{k}=AU_{k-1}+BV_{k-1}$$ satisfies $\|U_k\|_1=p^t$ for some $t$ (any $t\in\Bbb N$)?

How about just the case $t=0$ ($\|U_k\|_1=\|U_k\|_2=1$ and here $t$ is fixed to $0$)?

Could there be any useful tools here?